# Magento2 send Order information to Google Analytics when order from admin

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, event-observer, google-analytics

- Though Magento 2 has the inbuilt implementation to send the
  transaction/order details placed on webstore or frontend to Google
  Analytics, it lacks the same ability when orders are being placed
  from the Magento backend, the admin, or when orders are created
  programmatically.
- The problem Google Analytics won't match the reports generated from Magento.
- So I want to send order to google  save Google Analytics **Tracking Id**.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: i have not tried,even dont know how to do it

Comment: Hello @KetanBorada, did you try my solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I have checked and found that `module-google-analytics` is responsible for sending order analytics to Google.

It has `events.xml` at `magento2Root/vendor/magento/module-google-analytics/etc/frontend` with following content.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="googleanalytics_order_success" instance="Magento\GoogleAnalytics\Observer\SetGoogleAnalyticsOnOrderSuccessPageViewObserver" />
    </event>
    <event name="multishipping_checkout_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="googleanalytics_order_success" instance="Magento\GoogleAnalytics\Observer\SetGoogleAnalyticsOnOrderSuccessPageViewObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

So, it is calling observer on order success but only for front-end.

If you move this file form `frontend` to global, it will work for admin as well!

So new location for `events.xml` will be:

> magento2Root/vendor/magento/module-google-analytics/etc/events.xml

**Note:**

If above observer not work, you can also use `checkout_submit_all_after`, OR `sales_order_place_after`.

I have not tested above code due to unavailability of key.

If worked, do proper override in custom module.